# i want to make my weapon follow the cursor but Within limits of a circle plzzz helpp || unity2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

i want to make my weapon follow the cursor but Within limits of a circle plzzz helpp , i use this code and it works but the circle had a radius of 2 at (0,0) , i want to control the position of the circle to prevent making the weapon stuck in circle in (0,0) , help help

```
void Update()
{

    mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    rb.MovePosition(Vector2.ClampMagnitude(mousePos ,2.0f));
}
```

Comment: Please just stick to stating the problem as best you can. Begging and whining does nothing to make it easier to answer your question. It's far from clear what you're asking.

Comment: Just one more step to limit the length of the vector to 2 `Input.mousePosition.magnitude > 2 ? Input.mousePosition.normalized * 2 : Input.mousePosition`

Answer (score 0):

```
public Transform CentreOfCircle;

private void Update()
{
    Vector2 targetPosition = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
     rb.MovePosition(Vector2.ClampMagnitude(targetPosition - (Vector2)CentreOfCircle.position,Radius)+(Vector2)CentreOfCircle.position);
   
}
```

Here CentreOfCircle is the transform of the centre of the circle.

Comment: i guess you didn't understand what i want.| Vector2.ClampMagnitude its making an invisible circle at (0,0) around your vector ok , so when i said circle i don't mean an unityobject .

Comment: you can specify the position of the circle instead of using CentreOfCircle.position. I used a transform so that it is easy to change the position in the editor.